# Find the expression for $η$ (coefficient of viscosity). For the given condition

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

> A cube is sliding from wedge with a constant velocity and on  liquid of   $η$ coefficient of viscosity.The perpendicular distance between cube and layer of liquid is $x$ and the Length of cube is $a$. Then Find $η$.

WHAT I THINK-
We will equate forces i.e mg sinθ to viscous force ηΑdv/dx

Since the cube is moving with a constant velocity v so dv/dx should be zero and η=ZERO.

But the solution is 
η=(mg sinθ x)/a^2 v

Comment: Hi Neville and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: x is measured perpendicular to the wedge.  That is how Newton's law of viscosity comes into play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are wrong somewhere because constant velocity means Fnet=ma=0 viscous force equal to mgsintheta then i think you will able to solve it and what you refer for dv/dx mean velocity a layer which at dx length which is not equal to.zero